# How to see data inserted after a deletion in this database application?

Tags: android, database, android-layout, android-emulator, cursor

In this project all the functionality works good accept delete and display all data.
Once if i delete the record and after that if I am going to insert it, then it will inserted but I am not able to see it. I think it is inserted after some previous index value. So please tell me where I am wrong to delete all the records and display all records.
I am using cursor for it. and I don't know how to delete and display all the record by cursor. Please give me your view that where I am wrong.
The project code is here :

```
package com.example.databaseExample2;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ISBN = "isbn";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_PUBLISHER = "publisher";    
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "titles";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "isbn text not null, title text not null, " 
        + "publisher text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String isbn, String title, String publisher) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

//    public boolean deleteAllTitle()
//    {
//      return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,null, null);
//    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_ISBN,
                KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_PUBLISHER}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_ISBN, 
                        KEY_TITLE,
                        KEY_PUBLISHER
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    public void deleteAll()
    {
        this.db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String isbn, 
    String title, String publisher) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

And another file is here:

```
package com.example.databaseExample2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // define resources
        final Button display_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test_button);
        final EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);
        final Button insert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.insert);
        final Button delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
        final Button allDisplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.all);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); // create new database

        allDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                db.open();
                Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
                if (c.moveToLast())        
                {
//                  for(int i=0;c.getCount()>0;i++ )
//                  {
                        DisplayTitle(c);
                    //}
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No title found",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                }
                db.close();

            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                db.open();
                Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
                if(c.getCount()>0)
                {
                    db.deleteAll();
                }
                db.close();
                System.out.println("Record Delete.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //---add 2 titles---
                db.open();        
                long id;

                id = db.insertTitle("128","C-Programming","Dhiren");        
                id = db.insertTitle("256","Android","Shreyash");
                id = db.insertTitle("512","Android","Kandarp");
                id = db.insertTitle("1024","Android","Sweta");

                db.close();
                System.out.println("Record Inserted.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        display_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //---get a title---
                //String id1 = .toString();
                if(number.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Any Value...",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {

                    Integer id = (Integer)Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                    //System.out.println("The Id is:  "+id);
                    db.open();

                    Cursor c = db.getTitle(id);

                    if (c.moveToFirst())        
                    {
                        DisplayTitle(c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No title found",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                    }
                    db.close();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
    {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
                    "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +  "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                    "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }  
    public void DisplayAll(Cursor c)
    {
        for(int i = 0; c.getCount()!=0;i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
                    "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +  "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                   "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Any error you are getting ? Please paste your log-cat here

Comment: Thanks for reply. but I am not getting any errors, But the records are inserted after the some index that i have created before. Do one click on insert, then delete and then again insert the data. Now in second time the data are inserted after some index, So tell me where i am wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
            while(c.moveToNext())        
            {
              Toast.makeText(DatabaseActivity.this,c.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

**UpDate**

when you need to delete all no need to check other option.Just have to call delete

delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

```
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            db.open();              

                db.deleteAll();              
            db.close();
            System.out.println("Record Delete.");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**Update**

```
public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_ISBN,
                KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_PUBLISHER}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);

        return mCursor;
    }
```

**Update**

You have used sqlite auto increment field.So it will be increased forever until it exceeds maximum value.Suppose you have deleted 10 records.If you insert next time the id will be 11.It won't start from 1.See [official](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) docs

Comment: Ok Thanks. let me check it. But what about the delete all data??? I think i have to use delete Table. But how i have to use it that is i don't know. Please let me know how to delete all data.

Comment: Its works for me. But what about the delete all Data ?? Please help me  for that also.

Comment: Yes Thanks. But should i have to set the cursor to delete the all records ? And in your allDisply code i am not getting the first one record. Accept it, i got all record to be display. So please update the displayAll code.

Comment: why to think cursor when deleting records.And yes you will not get first record because you just cross the first record when selecting.to get all record see updated answer

Comment: So what can i do? if i want to see all the data ?

Comment: Ok. Let me try it. But What about to show all the records ? And there is also one mistake. Just insert the data in to the database. then delete it. Now again insert it. And now at this time while you see the records, it will inserted after the last index of previous data. Why it is happen ? where i am wrong ??

Comment: Ok All works great. but just there is one bug. that i have explained just before. Please help me in this also.

Comment: Yes Dear all works great. I can able to show all data and also able to delete all data. But let me help in the problem that i have explained just above in the comment.

Comment: Ok. Nice, i got the point. Thanks for your support. But now i want to do like that: when ever i want to insert the data and if there no any data then it should be start from the first. So what should i have to change in table ? Should i have to remove the primary key autoincrement ??? or what i else have to do ?

Comment: You can keep it primary key but have to remove auto increment and have to insert id as you like using insert statement

Comment: ok. Will you please give me the code what i have implement while inserting the data ?

Comment: It depends.suppose you have id 1,2,3.Now you deleted 2.What is the next id you want, 2 or 4.If 4 you have to find the max(id) before inserting and have to insert by incrementing 1.If 2 then you have to write code to find the missing id in between.then insert record with the id.Friend, you have to write some codes

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Well thanks for all support. Now i m fine. If i got any trouble then i will comment here ok ? Thanks again friend.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert data into a table, a cursor that is already open on the table may or may not see the newly added data.  If you close, reopen and reposition the cursor appropriately, you should see the new data.

Comment: Yes Thanks. But in My code if i delete it and then insert it again then it will stored after the index that is the last index of the previous deleted data. So am i wrong in inserting data ? or in set the cursor to insert the data ?